# ServiceStack OrmLite LastInsertId for Firebird provider

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

Is there a way to get the ID of the entity after it is inserted in Firebird?

If I do this `dbConn.Save(Entity);` I gen an exception `returning last inserted identity is not implemented on this db provider`.

I can do `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR GEN_....` but I was wondering if there is a simpler way. Thanks!

Comment: Whilist FIrebird is an community supported provider this should work, are you using the latest version of OrmLite?

Comment: Yes, but the entity I want to insert already das an ID, because it is coming from a web service. If I remove `[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]` annotation, it works.